# How to rename a file name without changing the extension

Tags: python-2.7

This is my example code to rename a file name with reference with a "csv" file.This csv file has a old name of a file in row[0],and new names in a row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hola.png) like this image

[image: Example csv file]

```
import csv
import os
    with open('New_Names_DDP.csv') as csvfile:
         reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
         for row in reader:
             oldname = row[0]
             newname = row[1]
             os.rename(oldname, newname)
```

But here i have a files with different extenstions like(.wav,.txt,.xml,.html).So I want to rename only file name with new name and add their extension automatically.Can you please help me for this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your sample CSV does not contain any extensions, just the filenames. So where are you getting the extensions from?

Comment: I need to read the file extension through code.If i have a file name with 100.txt here i want to rename the file name as CM0.txt and 101.wav changed as CM1.wav.like this

Comment: Am going to change only the file name.so that csv file contains only file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, because your problem and your code sample are talking about something else.

I assume what you want is:

1. Read all the files in some directory from the hard disk.
2. If the filename (without extension) is in column a, then rename it to whatever is in column b.

To do that:

```
import os
import csv
import glob

file_path = '/home/foo/bar/some/where/'
file_pattrn = '*.*'
file_names = {}

with open('somefile.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
       file_names[row[0]] = row[1]

for file in glob.iglob(file_path+file_pattrn):
    path, filename = os.path.split(file)
    filename_noext, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    new_filename = file_names.get(filename_noext, filename_noext)
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename),
              os.path.join(path, '{}{}'.format(new_filename, ext)))
```

Comment: Your assumption is exactly correct.But this code is not renaming my file.

Comment: So what is it doing instead?

Comment: If i remove "file_path" from this code.It is working fine.I got what i need.

Comment: You need to adjust the `file_path` to wherever the files are located on your system; otherwise it will only work if you place the script in the same directory as the files you are trying to rename.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os,csv,collections
all_files = os.listdir('.')
file_dict = defaultdict(str)#You could use a regular dict, but this has an advantage (see below)
with open('New_Names_DPP.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        file_dict[row[0]] = row[1]
for f in all_files:
    without_extension = f[:f.rfind('.')]#Note: assuming that no files like .tar.gz
    new_name = file_dict[without_extension]
    if new_name != '':#In the file_dict
        os.rename(f,new_name+f[f.rfind('.'):]#new_name plus extension
```

Let me know if this works